# How to use jupyter in vs code (docker)

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I connected via ssh to the server, I launched a container there, and I created a python virtual environment in the container. How do I now open an ipynb file via vs code while making jupyter notebook work inside a virtual environment inside a container

Comment: if I create an environment on the server and try to use it as an environment for jupyter, then I get 

`Running cells with 'segment-anything-venv' requires the ipykernel package.
Run the following command to install 'ipykernel' into the Python environment.` 

although ipykernel is installed in the `pip list`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.